# in search of SPE reference style file

Tags: bibliographies

does anyone know if there is a pre-configured SPE (the society of petroleum engineers) reference style file? I searched but I didn't come across with one. Or do you know any other style close to SPE?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you point to a source for the specifications of the citation style?

Comment: this pdf gives all the requirements starting from page 46: http://www.spe.org/authors/docs/styleguide.pdf. 
I am very new to latex, so I'm very far from being able to create a customized bst file

Comment: So you are using BibTeX?

Answer (score 1):

The example reference list items given in the SPE style guide you link to are entirely consistent with the Chicago Manual of Style, and I assume that the SPE style is based on it.